# custom border frame for GalleryView

Tags: android

I have created the Gallery view. but i want the border around the currently selected Gallery item can you anyone help me for this

Thanks
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

Create a an xml file in drawable folder like below

**gallery_back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail_roll" />
</selector>
```

Now set this gallery_back.xml as background of your gallery item. thats all

Comment: This can be done by the way I told you all they have done is that there is a image whose size is bit taller than gallery item but is transparent in nature so when the item is selected it looks up raised.

Comment: for that i need create xml right.now i have four image in gallery view. how to do for this can you explain to me because i am very new android i am struggling three days for this. please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Create a border/frame background something like this, use 9-patch tool for the same and then set this as the background of GalleryView or GridView item.